# Outputing the counted number of notifications on the view using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to output the number of counted notifications. Below is part of my Model and Controller. Am not sure what to put on the view

**My model**

```
//Counting notifications    

function notifications() {
    $area = $this->session->userdata('area'); 
    $this->db->count_all('consignment');
    $this->db->where('l_area',$area);    
}
```

**My Controller**

```
$data['notification']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->notification();
```

Comment: `$this->db->count_all` returns result don't using you call of `where` method

Comment: pls always be responsive to the answers given , mark it with green check and do upvote if you find it  helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

**In model**

```
//Counting notifications    

function notifications() 
{
    $area = $this->session->userdata('area'); 
    $this->db->where('l_area',$area);   
    $data = $this->db->from('my_table');  # Add table name here
    $result = $data->num_rows();
    return $result;

    # or

    $this->db->where('l_area',$area);  
    $this->db->from('my_table');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

**In Controller**

```
$data['notification']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->notification();
```

**In View**

```
echo $notification; # outputs like 49
```

---

**Links**

1. [Limiting or Counting Results - codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#limiting-or-counting-results)

---

**EDIT 01**

**In Controller**

```
$data['notification']=$this->Truckeraccount_model->notification(); 
print_r($data['notification']);
die;
```

Comment: Hey. now getting this error Object of a class CI_DB_mysql_result could not be converted to string  line 234    my line 234 is  <?php echo $notification; ?>

Comment: `print_r($data['notification']);die;` and post data in controller

Comment: this how i have done it now on my view ..   <?php
          
foreach ($notification->result() as &$row)  
{
?>   
<span class="label label-success"> <?php print_r($data['notification']);die; ?>
</span>
 <?php } ?>   
    
 but its not outputing anything

Comment: No in view no need foreach as well add that code in controller not view

Comment: What did you mean by post data in controller. sorry am new in codeigniter

Comment: now getting this  CI_DB_mysqli_result Object ( [conn_id] => mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: f373ea5dd5538761406a8022a4b8a374418b240e $ [client_version] => 50011 [connect_errno] => 0 [connect_error] => [errno] => 0 [error] => [error_list] => Array ( ) [field_count] => 6 [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket [info] => [insert_id] => 0 [server_info] => 5.6.21 [server_version] => 50621 [stat] => Uptime: 172012 Threads: 1 Questions: 9969 Slow queries:

Comment: 0 Opens: 1550 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 64 Queries per second avg: 0.057 [sqlstate] => 00000 [protocol_version] => 10 [thread_id] => 1351 [warning_count] => 0 ) [result_id] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 0 [type] => 0 ) [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => [row_data] => )

Comment: @Cooper whats going on this